# Is it possible to wrap the auto-generated classes from a WSDL file in a namespace?

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I would like to be able to maintain two different [SOAPClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php)s to communicate with two different SOAP servers in the same PHP script.  I can communicate with each server independently without issue, but both define their own versions of a class with the same name. When the WSDL-defined classes are imported into global scope, I get a multiple definition error. I do not have control of the servers, so I can't just change one of the names.

I'm thinking [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) would be the best way to solve this problem. Has anyone else run into this issue? Is there a simpler solution available?

Comment: Change one of the names.

Comment: I don't have control of the server, so I can't do that.

Comment: Then I guess namespaces is the ticket.